# Do Typescript hacks add performance burdens?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, optimization

I've been learning Typescript and dealing with some headaches caused by certain components not fitting the Typescript model either due to contributor issues or edge cases.

Like for example for `material-ui` and `react-router-dom`

```
// Javascript
<Button
  type="submit"
  fullWidth
  variant="contained"
  color="primary"
  component={RouteLink}
  to="/order"
  >
  Order
 </Button>
```

would become

```
// Typescript
<Button
  type="submit"
  fullWidth
  variant="contained"
  color="primary"
  {...{
    component: RouteLink,
    to: '/order'
  } as any}
  >
  Order
</Button>
```

before Typescript stops throwing errors. If no optimizations are performed by Typescript, I would assume the spreading operation would add an unnecessary burden. Do Typescript hacks add performance burdens or do they resolve to equivalent Javascript?

I'm sure that this will not be my last Typescript hack I learn but I hope its few and far between.

Answer (score 0):

TypeScripts purpose is to provide you with more type safety, which makes refactoring code easier and helps you catch errors at compile time rather than runtime. It wont affect the performance of your application in any way, since it is all compiled to pure JavaScript in the end.

I'm asuming your issue is that you're passing the "to" prop to the Button, when it's supposed to be passed to the RouteLink?
If that's the case, I'd suggest you try to do somehting like this.

````
<Button
  type="submit"
  fullWidth
  variant="contained"
  color="primary"
  component={() => <RouteLink to="/order" />}
>
  Order
</Button>
```
````

Comment: Setting it up as you stated makes material-ui complain `Property 'component' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes" ...` . I'm worried that extra Javascript is added due to Typescript. Doesn't it add more Javascript to spread the properties instead of directly setting the properties?